# How to evaluate the commutation relations in the Heisenberg equation of motion (Polarisation)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator, second-quantization

For a Hamiltonian in the following second quantisation form:\begin{equation}
H=\begin{aligned}
& \sum_{\vec{k}, s} E_{c, s}(\vec{k}) c_s^{\dagger}(\vec{k}) c_s(\vec{k})+\sum_{\vec{k}, s} E_{v, s}(\vec{k}) b_s^{\dagger}(\vec{k}) b_s(\vec{k}) \\
& +\frac{1}{A} \sum_{\vec{q}, \vec{k}, \vec{k}^{\prime}, s, s^{\prime}} U(q) c_s^{\dagger}(\vec{k}+\vec{q}) b_{s^{\prime}}^{\dagger}\left(\vec{k}^{\prime}-\vec{q}\right) b_{s^{\prime}}\left(\vec{k}^{\prime}\right) c_s(\vec{k})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The equation of motion can be listed as$$
i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}(c_s^{\dagger}(k+Q) b_s(k))=[c_s^{\dagger}(k+Q)b_s(k),H]
$$
This is where $c_s$, $E_{c,s}$ represents the conduction band and its energies and $b_s$, $E_{v,s}$ represents the valence band and its energies.
I know that the Hamiltonian itself can be split up into the separate components of the Hamiltonian itself, but they way to evaluate it us unclear, as the result for one part should be the following:$$
[c_s^{\dagger}(\vec{k}+\vec{Q})b_s(\vec{k}),E_{c, s}(\vec{k}) c_s^{\dagger}(\vec{k}) c_s(\vec{k})]=-E_{c,s}(\vec{k}+\vec{Q})c_s^{\dagger}(\vec{k}+\vec{Q})b_s(\vec{k})
$$
Perhaps this is an obvious result however I do not see through explicitly evaluating the commutation relation how you obtain this.

Hamiltonian and information in this text comes from the paper 'Many-body theory of the optical conductivity of excitons and trions in two-dimensional materials' by Rana et al. (2020)

Comment: $[A,BC]=[A,B]C+B[A,C]$ helps.

Comment: @Hyperon I believe that the $c$ here are Fermions, so this relation is less helpful (since one need to use the anti-commutator) and a more useful one is $[A, BC] = \{A, B\}C - B \{A, C\}$

Comment: @yyy Yes, in a first step the version with the commutator and then the one with the anti-commutator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean that the commutation relation is $\left[c^{\dagger}(\vec{k}+\vec{Q})b_s(\vec{k}), \sum_{\vec{k}'} E_{c,s}(\vec{k}')c^{\dagger}(\vec{k}')c(\vec{k}')\right]$ as the Hamiltonian has a sum over all $\vec{k}$ and you are looking at a specific one. For this commutation relation, $b$ is completely inert as it commutes with everything in the other part of the commutation relation $[b_s(\vec{k}, c^{\dagger}(\vec{q})c(\vec{q})] = 0$ for all $\vec{q}$, so we are left with
$$ \left[c^{\dagger}(\vec{k}+\vec{Q}), \sum_{\vec{k}'} E_{c,s}(\vec{k}')c^{\dagger}(\vec{k}')c(\vec{k}')\right] = -E_{c,s}(\vec{k}+\vec{Q})c^{\dagger}(\vec{k}+\vec{Q})$$
from (in short-hand) $[c^{\dagger}_k, c^{\dagger}_q c_q ] =-\delta_{k,q}c^{\dagger}_k$ which you can see from multiple ways but the most convenient one is using $c^{\dagger}_k c_q + c_q c^{\dagger}_k = \delta_{k,q}$ and $c^{\dagger}_k c^{\dagger}_q + c^{\dagger}_q c^{\dagger}_k = 0$ to get $-\delta_{k,q} c^{\dagger}_q + c^{\dagger}_q c_q c^{\dagger}_k-  c^{\dagger}_q c_q c^{\dagger}_k = \delta_{k,q} c^{\dagger}_q$.

Notice that working in Heisenberg picture doesn't change the algebra of commutation relations, as for $[A_S, B_S] = C_S$ (Schroedinger picture) we get in Heisenberg picture $$[A_H(t), B_H(t)] = [U^{\dagger}(t)A_SU(t), U^{\dagger}(t)B_SU(t)] = U^{\dagger}(t)[A_S, B_S]U(t) = U^{\dagger}(t)C_SU(t) =C_H(t)$$

Comment: edited to add the important sign change ($[c^{\dagger}_k, c^{\dagger}_q c_q ] = -\delta_{k,q}c^{\dagger}_k$ and not with plus sign as I wrote initially)

Comment: Yes, I see this now, I missed the sign in the body of the question I wrote. Would the method you described be directly application to the interaction term in the listed in the Hamiltonian above

Comment: Yes, but you should note that there you also have a non-trivial commutation relations between $b$ and $b^{\dagger}b$ that appear in the interaction. It might require some more work to get that right, but the idea is the same